# How to reduce height of SmartMaterialSpinner?

Tags: java, android

I want ro reduce the height as small as , i need ..
i used library "com.chivorn.smartmaterialspinner.SmartMaterialSpinner".
when i used less than 65dp height, text is invisible.
but i didn,t find any way ..

```
<com.chivorn.smartmaterialspinner.SmartMaterialSpinner
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingLeft="2dp"
  android:paddingBottom="0dp"
  app:smsp_arrowPaddingBottom="0dp"
  app:smsp_arrowSize="15dp"
  app:smsp_baseColor="#FF5252"
  app:smsp_floatingLabelColor="#1976D2"
  app:smsp_floatingLabelText="Sale"
  app:smsp_hint="Select Sale Type"
  app:smsp_hintColor="#388E3C"
  app:smsp_isSearchable="true"
  app:smsp_itemColor="#512DA8"
  app:smsp_itemListColor="#7C4DFF"                            
  app:smsp_itemListHintBackgroundColor="#808080"
  app:smsp_itemListHintColor="#FFFFFF"
  app:smsp_multilineError="false"
  app:smsp_selectedItemListColor="#FF5252"
  app:smsp_underlineColor="#FF5252"
  app:smsp_underlineSize="0dp" />
```

Comment: Edit `android:layout_height` like `android:layout_height="20dp"`

Comment: it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with it but as it seems here: [SmartMaterialSpinner](https://github.com/Chivorns/SmartMaterialSpinner) in the documentation it should be `smsp_itemSize` it changes the itemsize of the spinner. This setting seems to be missing in your xml.

Comment: it reduces size of text(10sp), when i used height of spinner 65, it looks bulky, then i reduced height (35 0r 45), text is hidden.